# I want to keep the textboxes as readonly in a view, the textboxes are strongly typed using any class names or ID;s in one event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put the the textboxes as readonly in MVC strongly type textboxes using class name or ID's in an event(1 event) instead of keeping `readonly=readonly` for every textbox statically why because I do have 50 + textboxes are there in one VIEW.

Eg:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AGENT_TITLE, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "left" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AGENT_TITLE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AGENT_TITLE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Comment: You could javascript/jquery to add the attribute or you could create you own html helper extension method (say `@Html.ReadonlyFor()`)

Comment: can you please give me an example as I have tried it with like  $('.form-control input[type=text]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

Comment: I want to keep the textboxes as readonly when the page gets loaded

Comment: `$('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');` should do it (you had a space between the class name and element type)

Comment: But the real question is why would you post back 50+ values completely unchanged!

Comment: actually I would like to edit only 3 in that and remaining all will be read only

Comment: Then don't use textboxes - use `@Html.DisplayFor()` inside a div element styled to look like a textbox (borders etc). Posting back all that extra data will just degrade performance. Get the model from the repository and just update the 3 properties you edit.

Comment: while page is loading except those 3 textboxes will be writable remaining all will be readonly can I have

Comment: okay but now I don't want to chance the textboxes that are already declared in the view. The only thing is I need to keep 47 as readonly and 3 will be writable in programatically without changing the html code in a view.

Comment: I would like to change it in dynamically like using Jquery or Javascript while page is loading.